# Is there a way to add on / change or remove the ? (question mark) in a url?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a search bar on one of my websites in Github.
This is the code for the search bar:

```
<!-- HTML for SEARCH BAR -->
<div id="header">
<form id="newsearch" method="get" action="https://itac85.github.io/Basic-Search-Engine">
<input type="text" class="textinput" name="search" size="21" maxlength="120"><input type="submit" value="Search!" class="button">
</form>
<div class="tfclear"></div>
</div>
```

When I try this, it adds in the URL `/?search=whatever`, which causes the link to not work.

And if I change `method="get"` to `method="post"`, GitHub gives me a **405 Not Allowed** error.

Is there a way (in html, css, and / or JavaScript) to remove the `?` entirely, or change it to something else such as `search?search=whatever`?

Comment: gh-pages is not dynamic, i.e GET only on static content, which is why posting to it is yielding error 405 Method Not Allowed

Comment: You can use the submit event generated by the form to form a link and navigate to it,  or start your search logic on a page that reads the query string.

Comment: @JoshuaWade Yes, I can change the ```?search``` to be anything else, but I don't know how to make it something such as ```search?s=whatever```.

Comment: If you want it to be `search?search=whatever`, the action URL needs to end with `search`.

Comment: The URL is always `<action>?<form-parameters>`

Comment: Why don't you just change the action to whatever you want before `?search=whatever`?

Answer (score -1):

Here is how to change it to something else:

Change the `<action="example.com">` to be `<action="example.com/example">`, which will change the URL `example.com/?example=whatever` to be `example.com/example?example=whatever`.